# Adding land survey info to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, land-survey

I am looking for help digitizing or adding info from survey plans into QGIS.

In this example I'm trying to add the lease boundaries highlighted in yellow and the pipeline right of ways to the right of it.

Right now I just eyeballed a feature (well centre) so I used the advanced digitizing tools to draw from it based on the lengths and angles noted in the survey drawing, but I was wondering what the proper way to do this would be.

Part of the problem is I do not know how to tell what angle the lease is sitting on.

Maybe QGIS is not the best open source tool for this task.

[image: Survey Drawing]

[Survey Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdqIQ.jpg)

[image: Detail Survey]

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you saying the yellow square is an accurate representation of the lease or just your best guess and you're trying to find an accurate representation?

Comment: Everything on this survey is accurate, i just don't know how to draw it in qgis accurately.

Comment: Oh, can't you do a pixel-to-latitude-longitude conversion of the survey and draw the result as polygons on qgis? I sense I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you know the coordinates for one of the corners of the yellow square and do you know the bearings and distances along the lines of the yellow square?